# DB2 Resource BIND Error: DSNT500I -DBS1 DSNTBCM1 RESOURCE UNAVAILABLE

Tags: db2, zos, tivoli

Trying to run a BIND job for the new Tivoli OMEGAMON XE DB2 upgrade.
I'm having difficulties running the **RKD2SAM(OMBPSS01)** job to bind the OMEGAMON Server DB2 plan KO2PLAN.

```
JCL:
//OMEGAPL  EXEC  PGM=IKJEFT01                                                 
//STEPLIB  DD    DISP=SHR,DSN=SYS1.DB2DR.DSNLOAD                                
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*                                                       
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                       
//SYSTSIN  DD *                                                              
  DSN SYSTEM(DBS1)                                                           
  BIND PLAN     (KO2PLAN)        +                                           
       PKLIST   (KO2OM520.*)     +                                           
       OWNER    (SOFDB2)         +                                           
       ACTION   (REPLACE)        +                                           
       EXPLAIN  (NO)             +                                           
       RETAIN                    +                                           
       VALIDATE (BIND)           +                                           
       ENCODING (EBCDIC)         +                                           
       ISOLATION(UR)                                                         
  END                                                                        
/*                                                                           

SYSOUT:
DSNT500I  -DRS1 DSNTBCM1 RESOURCE      UNAVAILABLE                                    
       REASON 00E30083                                                       
       TYPE 00000800                                                         
       NAME KO2PLAN                                                          
DSNT201I  -DRS1  BIND FOR PLAN KO2PLAN  NOT SUCCESSFUL
```

Random and poorly run forums indicate that WLM might be using this resource.  How can perform the BIND or find what is using that resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REASON 00E30083` means a deadlock on `TYPE 00000800` (plan) with `NAME KO2PLAN`. Since you cannot (re)bind a plan that is in use by an application, one might assume that OMEGAMON is running, thus preventing the bind.

As an aside, in addition to "random and poorly run forums" it is often useful to refer to the product (in this case DB2 for z/OS) documentation.